# Should I avoid a one hour sleep()?

Tags: php

I'm using the DigitalOcean API to create droplets when my web application needs the extra resources. Because of the way DigitalOcean charges (min. one hour increments), I'd like to keep a created server on for an hour so it's available for new tasks after the initial task is completed.

I'm thinking about formatting my script this way:

```
<?php
createDroplet($dropletid);
$time = time();
// run resource heavy task
sleep($time + 3599);
deleteDroplet($dropletid);
```

Is this the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You do know that `sleep` wants the argument as seconds and not a timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like a good idea, but the code is so simple, nothing can compete with that. You would need to make sure your script can run, at least, for that long.

Note that `sleep()` should not have `$time` as an argument. It sleeps for the given number of seconds. `$time` contains many, many seconds.

I am worried that the script might get interrupted, and you will never delete the droplet. Not much you can do about that, given this script.

Also, the `sleep()` itself might get interrupted, causing it to sleep much shorter than you want. A better sleep would be:

```
$remainingTime = 3590;
do {
  $remainingTime = sleep($remainingTime);
} while ($remainingTime > 0);
```

This will catch an interrupt of `sleep()`. This is under the assumption that `FALSE` is `-1`. See the manual on `sleep()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Then there's the problem that you want to sleep for exactly 3599 seconds, so that you're only charged one hour. I wouldn't make it so close to one hour. You have to leave some time for DigitalOcean to execute stuff and log the time. I would start with 3590 seconds and make sure that always works.

Finally: What are the alternatives? Clearly this could be a cron job. How would that work? Suppose you execute a PHP script every minute, and you have a database entry that tells you which resource to allocate at a certain start time and deallocate at a certain expire time. Then that script could do this for you with an accurary of about a minute, which should be enough. Even if the server crashes and restarts, as long as the database is intact and the script runs again, everything should go as planned. I know, this is far more work to implement, but it is the better way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, setting a cron job does seem to much more robust, and use less resources than looping for an hour.